# Put a Javascript variable into a innerHTML code

Tags: javascript, innerhtml

I'm creating a table dynamic table with Javascript:

```
var row = table.insertRow(-1);
var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
var cell2 = row.insertCell(1);
var cell3 = row.insertCell(2);
var cell4 = row.insertCell(3);
var cell5 = row.insertCell(4);
```

I want to fill the cell5 with some innerHTML with a Javascript variable inside

```
var add = aux[i].split("#");
cell5.innerHTML = "<img src='MatrixLogos/add[3]' width='100' height='25'/>";
```

but this give add[3] in the html instead of the value inside add[3].

My question is how to escape the variable inside the innerHTML code, so it shows me is value and not the declaration.

Comment: There's currently no syntax for string interpolation. You can create a method that defines such behavior for strings, or you can simply concatenate the values in.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Use "+".

```
var add = aux[i].split("#");
cell5.innerHTML = "<img src='MatrixLogos/"+add[3]+"' width='100' height='25'/>";
```

Comment: Thank you pamrnas it was helpful

Comment: What if the value is saying undefined but after logging the variable in console we can see the result

Answer (score 2):

Use `String` concatenation like

```
var add = aux[i].split("#");
var string = "This is to " + add[3] + " test with value";
```

Where as in your case, statement will become:

```
cell5.innerHTML = "<img src='MatrixLogos/"+add[3]+"' width='100' height='25'/>";
```