# How to store json value (unix-timestamp) in javascript variable and print in a for-loop?

Tags: javascript, json, for-loop, tumblr, unix-timestamp

Right now, I am working with the Tumblr API (v2) and trying to accomplish something I have never done before. I am a beginner with Javascript and tried to find a solution for my problem, but after several hours of trial and error I wasn’t able to solve it.

Anyway – This is the code I am using:

```
<script>
    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: 'https://api.tumblr.com/v2/blog/sitename.tumblr.com/posts/video?api_key=APIKEY&tag=featured',
        data: {
            get_param: 'value'
        },
        dataType: 'jsonp',
        success: function(data) {                
            for (i = 3; i <= 6; i++) {
                var time = moment.unix(data.response.posts[i].timestamp).format("MMMM DD, YYYY");
                $('#topvid').append('<div class="uk-width-1-2 uk-width-1-4@s">\
                                    <div class="cm-topfour"><div class="uk-inline-clip uk-transition-toggle uk-light">\
                                    <img src="'+ data.response.posts[i].thumbnail_url +'" alt="">\
                                    <div class="uk-position-center uk-text-center"><a href="" class="uk-icon-link uk-transition-fade" uk-icon="icon: play-circle; ratio: 3.0"></a></div>\
                                    <div class="uk-overlay uk-position-top cm--catflag"><span>'+ data.response.posts[i].tags[0] +'</span></div>\
                                    <div class="uk-overlay uk-position-bottom cm--itemfooter">\
                                    <div class="uk-float-left">'+ document.write(time) +'</div>\
                                    <div class="uk-float-right">Notes '+ data.response.posts[i].note_count +'</div>\
                                    </div></div></div></div>');
            }                
        }
    });
</script>
```

What I am doing try to do here is the following: 
There is a value called timestamp within the json object, which is a Unix timestamp (e.g.: timestamp: 1512838102). To format the timestamp I am using moment.js. Moment.js is working fine, if I use it outside of the code above.

Next I did try to store the timestamp inside of a variable (time) and inside the loop. I am not even sure, if this is the right way. After I did this, I tried to output the var within the append-part. I tried several ways, but all I got so far was “undefined” or nothing.

I am sure, I am doing it all wrong and I did mess it up at some point.
Again, what I am trying to is: Use the timestamp value with in the loop inside the moment.js script and print the final value within the append-part, so it is visible on the page for each iteration.

Thanks for your help in advance!

Comment: Are you expecting the time to be printed here? `<div class="uk-float-left">'+ document.write(time) +'</div>` because you are just printing a string...

Comment: Yes, exactly. I thought, if I add the time via `var time = moment.unix(data.response.posts[i].timestamp).format("MMMM DD, YYYY");`, that I would be able to print it later. But maybe I am just mixing it up.

Comment: Worth noting: there don't appear to be any functions defined inside the for loop, so this isn't likely to be related to scope (variables declared with `var` can behave in an unintuitive manner when used inside closures created inside loops, so that's an obvious first thing to check for).

Comment: I think you are just appending a string. Look into `.innerHTML` to display javascript between HTML tags. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16467536/put-a-javascript-variable-into-a-innerhtml-code Look at this question.