# is it possible to assign the textContent of an element to be HTML code in JS?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I know you can use backticks to do this regularly, but are you able to concatenate those backticks?

For example, will

```
let bar = 42;
let foo = document.createElement("div");
foo.innerHTML = `<div> this number is ` + bar + ` </div>`;
```

be..

```
<div> this number is 42 </div>
```

If not, is there another way to do this? I am trying to create create elements with textContent that is only in my JS file

Comment: they're just strings in the end, so yes that will work.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Put a Javascript variable into a innerHTML code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16467536/put-a-javascript-variable-into-a-innerhtml-code)

Comment: Actually Template Literals can be interpolated: `text text ${expression} text` is equivalent to  `"text text "+expression+" text"`

Comment: zer00ne is correct

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Backticks are meant to make it easier for you to combine strings. For example,

```
`This is a variable: ${testVariable}`;
```

is the same thing as

```
"This is a variable: " + testVariable;
```

In your case, both will result in a string, so you would be able to use both of them to create elements.

Comment: @keurig no problem. Accept the answer  if it worked for you to let others know it worked as well.

Comment: Why use backticks here if the double quotes is easier to write and no curly braces and dollar needed (keep it simple). On the other hand, no `plus` needed, so I get it.

Comment: @Timo for just one variable at the end of a string, backticks aren't really necessary but I generally use backticks because it makes it far easier to include variables in a string, and also allow you to use single quotes and double quotes inside the string.